# How to parse JSON array of string arrays

Tags: c#, json

Lets say I get the following json data from a web service which I can't change.

```
[
    [
        "Header1",
        "Header2",
        "Header3",
        "Header4"
    ],
    [
        "FirstValue1",
        "FirstValue2",
        "FirstValue3",
        "FirstValue4"
    ],
    [
        "SecondValue1",
        "SecondValue2",
        "SecondValue3",
        "SecondValue4"
    ]
]
```

[jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) tells me that it is valid json and from what I know I would agree.

But somehow I'm wondering is there any "easy" way to deserialize this to a class. Each of the values in the second and third array belongs to the corresponding header in the first array.

I know how to use Json.NET but can't get my head around on how to use it with this data structure.

Comment: You deserialize the data and then reorganize however you want.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simple - you can use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` to deserialize it to a `string[][]`:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var json = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
        string[][] array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[][]>(json);
        Console.WriteLine(array[1][3]); // FirstValue4
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use the `string` class and deserialzie it using `Json.NET`.

```
string[][] values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[][]>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

A better option could be to use

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

string json = @"{
  CPU: 'Intel',
  Drives: [
    'DVD read/writer',
    '500 gigabyte hard drive'
  ]
}";

JObject o = JObject.Parse(json); 

string CPU = o.CPU;
int NumDrives = o.Drives.Count;
```

Source: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm

Comment: That's not going to work. `JObject` doesn't know about `CPU` or `Drives`. You'd need to use `dynamic` for that. And your JSON is completely different from the question asked.

Comment: It was an example... and if you tired the code... you would see what it does work.

Comment: It doesn't work - as expected I get 'JObject' does not contain a definition for 'CPU' and no accessible extension method 'CPU' accepting a first argument of type 'JObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)